# Does a size of pixel differ in different devices?

Tags: pixel

Just a curiosity, since my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900829/why-pixel-is-considered-as-a-css-relative-unit) was put onto hold and couldn't communicate any further on that question, so my curiosity according to [this link](http://auctionrepair.com/pixels.html) is whether the size of the pixel changes in different environments physically such as computer screen, ipda, mobile devices. I was wondering about that and if that does then can pixel be considered relative unit in relative to computer devices? Other curiosity is that what I found out from the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1QRj817uNo) on youtube, which says that the size of pixel changes logically when we change the resolution of the screen, but even after changing the resolutions, I could not find the size of image being changed. Hence, I would like to get your answers whether the size of the pixel stays the same in every devices or they change just logically according to the resolution of the screen and resolution of image.

Comment: Your computer system and/or your OS does not support switching to other resolutions? Then plug in a larger or smaller monitor -- it will have the same number of pixels (because your OS does not seem to support changing this) but each pixel will be larger or smaller. Even comparing this year's iPhone against last year's one will show this.

Comment: @Jongware: Of course, my OS supports switching, but I couldn't see the difference in dimension of image being changed in lower resolution. I used screen ruler to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Consider screens with a native maximum (physical) resolution of 1600x900.  If you have a 21" monitor with that resolution, the physical pixel size will be different than a 42" monitor with the same native maximum resolution.  Logical resolution is different, but the (logical) pixel grouping will similarly be different with disparate underlying physical display size characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does OS use logical pixel grouping in different resolutions, I mean when we manually change the screen resolution? Since, the physical size of the pixel changes in different physical screen resolution, can the pixel be considered as a relative unit in relative to the screen resolution?